# How to submit two forms on same page?

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, struts

Case:

I have two forms 
1> Own Customized Form say form1.
2> Form rendering from third party java script call say form2.

Previously there was only one form 
(no third party form) with same fields.
Thus I was submitting it using single submit button.
Lets say I was calling Action1 for my old form.

The third party form has own submit button and  it post values (Not all. Only Third Party 
values ) to own controller and returns response .

I don't want  to ask user to submit twice on same page.

I want to submit both forms on old submit button and hide third party submit button.

I can change the response URL (where to land to get  third party form submit response ).

I am thinking to hide third party submit button with css and call click/submit that when I 
click old submit button using javascript.

Lets set response landing page for third party  to Action1.

But if I land on old action ie Action1 I cant able to get old customized form element?

I am stuck in this scenario.

Can you have any better solution to this?

[Using struts framework and jsp for rendering form.]

Comment: You won't be able to submit two forms at once per the usual way with buttons. You could submit one form via javascript, once the response returns, then submit the second form (either also through javascript, or the normal action="whatever" method)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you may try this,

```
$("#submit").livequery('click', function() {
    var form = $("#second_form");
    var action = form.attr("action");
    var serialized_form = form.serialize();
    $.post(action, serialized_form, submit_first);
});

function submit_first(val) {
   $("#first_form").submit();
}
```

2nd option

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(),
        function(){
            $.post( $("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").seriallize(),
                function(){
                    alert("Now what?");
                });
        });
});
```

Hope this also helpful, [Submit multiple forms with jQuery and Ajax.](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/submit-multiple-forms-jquery-ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use JavaScript to copy one form's parameters to the other.

The same mechanism can be used to remove the other form's submit button.